# Unreliable outgoing network connectivity

Tags: networking, server

I'm running Ubuntu Server (16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-112-generic x86_64)) on dedicated hardware (not a VM). I can reliably ping the server from outside. I can reliably ping localhost. But pinging 8.8.8.8 (or anything else), including the Gateway IP, fails for about 15 seconds before it finally succeeds and then reliably works. Then I stop it, wait about a minute, and it'll fail again no the next try.

I'm  relatively new to Ubuntu and have tried many things I've found in searching but nothing has improved the situation. Any ideas?

Here's my interfaces file

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno2
iface eno2 inet static
    address 2XX.84.55.15
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 2XX.84.55.0
    broadcast 2XX.84.55.255
    gateway 2XX.84.55.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version? `lsb_release -d` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry. Version Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-112-generic x86_64)

Comment: Please remove the network and broadcast lines entirely and then do: `sudo down eno2 && sudo ifup -v eno2` The -v for verbose will produce some clues as to what, if anything, went wrong. Then do: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` followed by `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured it out. The problem was actually in the router, not the server. The router was querying the server for Single Sign On info and wouldn't pass through the packets until it timed out. So I told it to Bypass SSO for that server and it now works!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.